# How can I get this switch to pick just one of the 3 options?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Please make a selection between 1 and 3");
        int choice = s.nextInt();

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 3: System.out.println("Can a brother get some fries with that?");
        case 2: System.out.println("Cheeseburger it is.... fatso");
        case 1: System.out.println("Good choice, you could use a salad");
        break;
        default: System.out.println("Not a valid selection bruh");
        }
```

Comment: put `break;` after each independent `case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch (choice) {
    case 3: System.out.println("Can a brother get some fries with that?"); break;
    case 2: System.out.println("Cheeseburger it is.... fatso"); break;
    case 1: System.out.println("Good choice, you could use a salad"); break;
    default: System.out.println("Not a valid selection bruh"); break;
}
```

I literally just added the `break`s after each `case` so it will exit your `switch` if it encounters either `1,2,3` or none of them.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! For some reason I just assumed that the break would turn off the switch before it got to the correct case.

Comment: No problem. Without a break after each case the switch just 'falls through' all the other options instead of stopping.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the break statements...

Answer (score 0):

You need a break; after each of the cases.

```
 switch (choice)
{
    case 3: System.out.println("Can a brother get some fries with that?");
    break;
    case 2: System.out.println("Cheeseburger it is.... fatso");
    break;
   case 1: System.out.println("Good choice, you could use a salad");
   break;
   default: System.out.println("Not a valid selection bruh");
   break;
}
```